# Can someone still get the title of "Club Master?"

Tags: titles

In the 90's I was reading British Chess Magazine. I remember an article about the new title of "Club Master": a title given for strong chess performance at a club level. I have no idea what FIDE rating, if any, was required. I think that the British Chess Federation [BCF] gave the title rather than FIDE. Can someone still get this title?

Comment: As I understand it, these titles exist mostly for the purpose of encouraging juniors, and are considered rather a vanity for adult players, since a holder of the ECF "Club Master" title is not even close to being an actual master.  The way the whole thing has been done is rather a shame - the US national master title is quite well respected, but the silliness of the lower ECF titles like "Team Master" and "Club Master" effectively prevents the ECF National Master title from functioning as an equivalent in terms of prestige.

Comment: That's interesting; the BCF magazine in the 90's, discussing the introduction of the Club Master title, was using adult players as examples rather than juniors. I agree that there is a silliness and a devaluation in these titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. According to the [ECF website](https://www.englishchess.org.uk/master-points-system/) it costs £10 and a number of different titles are available for ECF members:

> (a) **Chess Maestro**
>   A player must achieve a grade of at least 95
>   on any ECF official grading list.
>   (b) **Team Master**
>   A player must achieve a grade of at least 120 on any ECF official grading list.
>   (c) **Club Master**
>   A player must achieve a standard play A or B grade of at least 145 on an ECF official grading list.
>   (d) **County Master**
>   A player must achieve a standard play A grade of at least 170 on an ECF official grading list.
>   (e) **Regional Master**
>   A player must achieve a standard play A grade of at least 185 in two successive seasons on ECF official grading lists (note – grades must be 12 months apart e.g. July 2012, July 2013).
>   (f) **National Master**
>   A player must achieve a standard play A grade of at least 200 in two successive seasons on ECF official grading lists (note – grades must be 12 months apart e.g. July 2012, July 2013).

Comment: Interesting that Club Master is the only one of these that I ever heard about. Besides maybe National Master.